# eclipse: Do not show references from binary types in call hierarchy

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to remove binary references from "call hierarchy" (Ctrl-Alt-H) ?
Our project setup is such that for many members we have duplicated references (one reference from source file and one from the jar file with class compiled from that source file). The navigation is inconvenient and I wondering if any ways to fix that is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call hierarchy can be limited in scope to a working set. You just need to set one up to exclude all your libraries.

If you click on the white down arrow in the top right of the Call Hierarchy window a popup menu will appear. Choose Search Scope/Working set and then select or set up the working set you want. A working set can include a source folder or a jar. Once set up your working sets will appear at the bottom of the Search Scope menu so you can access them quickly in future.

Comment: I can move our projects with created jars to new working set, but some of these projects also contains their own code and references from that code will be unavailable, right?

Comment: Just add the source folder and leave the jars out. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered another way to accomplish this, and since this question is one of the top results in google, I thought it would be good to add it as an answer.

In the Call Hierarchy view, one can click the 'View Menu' (the downward facing arrow) and select "Search In...". In the window that pops up, the user can un-check the options they want to exclude. For example, I only have 'Sources' and 'Required projects' checked.